# How can i count the pixiel values at the same latitude in Raster Layer for R?

Tags: r, raster

I have a NDVI(Normalized Differnce Vegetation Index) Raster object, now i want to count the pixiel values at the same latitude.Like, i want to know the pixel value in 30°N latittude.How can i do that in R?

But I find no function could do that in "Raster" or "terra" package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem sloved.

I find a question satisfied my request.It was an oversight on my part, not noticing. You can find the question in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346351/r-how-to-get-raster-values-across-a-latitude-band) and the answer is friendly.